# yield оператор в async методе без IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, асинхронность, итераторы, yield

Как мне возвращать значение через `yield` в асинхронном методе БЕЗ использования `IAsyncEnumerable`?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> MyEnumerableMethod()
{
   foreach(var item in smthCollection)
   {
      yield return item; //CS1624 Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> is not an iterator interface type
   }
}
```

Comment: `public async IAsyncEnumerable<MyClass>`

Comment: @aepot это умеем, интересно хитрый-костыльный способ

Comment: Тогда в чем вопрос?

Comment: @aepot в том, как обойтись без `IAsyncEnumerable`

Comment: Убрать `async` модификатор.

Comment: А не убирая `async`?

Comment: Не убирая, никак. В чем смысл? Понять не могу.

Comment: @aepot смысла никакого в этом нет. Мне просто хотелось знать, можно или нет и если можно - то как. Но раз никак - тоже отлично, можете оформить ответ из одного слова: "никак"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта использования итератора, позволяющие применять ключевое слово `yield`:

Синхронный

```
IEnumerable<T>
IEnumerator<T>
```

И асинхронный

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<T>
async IAsyncEnumerator<T>
```

Больше никаких вариантов сигнатур нет, это ограничение зашито на уровне языка C#.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере нет `await`, да и вообще не совсем понятно чего вы пытаетесь добиться. Но если предположить, что до вашего цикла есть какая-то асинхронная операция, то можно цикл вынести в отдельный локальный метод, тогда у вас будет возможность использовать `yield return`, т.к. этот будет не асинхронный. Например:

```cs
async Task<IEnumerable<int>> Test()
{
    var smthCollection = await GetSmth();
    
    return Get(smthCollection);
    
    IEnumerable<int> Get(IEnumerable<int> smthCollection)
    {
        foreach(var item in smthCollection)
        {
            // что-то делаем с item
            yield return item; 
        }
    }
}
```

Но тогда у лучше использовать `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. А так да, я согласен, что использовать `async` и `yield` без `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>>` должен возвращать **одну** задачу, внутри которой завёрнут `IEnumerable` (и один из ответов показывает, как это можно сделать).
Когда используется `return`, то `C#` сам оборачивает возвращаемое значение в `Task`, а что вы хотите обернуть в `Task`, когда делаете `yield return`, компилятору непонятно - это должно быть много `Task`-ов или что? Поэтому так нельзя.